# np.nanmax() over all except one axis - is this the best way?

Tags: python, numpy

For a numpy array of dimension `n`, I'd like to apply np.nanmax() to `n-1` dimensions producing a 1 dimensional array of maxima, ignoring all values set to `np.nan`.

```
q         = np.arange(5*4*3.).reshape(3,4,5) % (42+1)
q[q%5==0] = np.nan
```

producing:

```
array([[[ nan,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
        [ nan,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
        [ nan,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.],
        [ nan,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.]],

       [[ nan,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.],
        [ nan,  26.,  27.,  28.,  29.],
        [ nan,  31.,  32.,  33.,  34.],
        [ nan,  36.,  37.,  38.,  39.]],

       [[ nan,  41.,  42.,  nan,   1.],
        [  2.,   3.,   4.,  nan,   6.],
        [  7.,   8.,   9.,  nan,  11.],
        [ 12.,  13.,  14.,  nan,  16.]]])
```

If I know ahead of time that I want to use the **last axis** as the remaining dimension, I can use the `-1` feature in `.reshape()` and do this:

```
np.nanmax(q.reshape(-1, q.shape[-1]), axis=0)
```

which produces the result I want:

```
array([ 12.,  41.,  42.,  38.,  39.])
```

However, suppose I don't know ahead of time *to which one of the axes* that I don't want to apply the maximum? Suppose I started with `n=4` dimensions, and wanted it to apply to all axes except the `m`th axis, which could be 0, 1, 2, or 3? Would have to actually use a conditional if-elif-else ?

Is there something that would work like a hypothetical `exeptaxis=m`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `axis` argument of `nanmax` can be a tuple of axes over which the maximum is computed.  In your case, you want that tuple to contain all the axes except `m`.  Here's one way you could do that:

```
In [62]: x
Out[62]: 
array([[[[  4.,   3.,  nan,  nan],
         [  0.,   2.,   2.,  nan],
         [  4.,   5.,  nan,   3.],
         [  2.,   0.,   3.,   1.]],

        [[  2.,   0.,   0.,   1.],
         [ nan,   3.,   0.,  nan],
         [  0.,   1.,  nan,   2.],
         [  5.,   4.,   0.,   1.]],

        [[  4.,   0.,   2.,   0.],
         [  4.,   0.,   4.,   5.],
         [  3.,   4.,   1.,   0.],
         [  5.,   3.,   4.,   3.]]],


       [[[  2.,  nan,   6.,   4.],
         [  3.,   1.,   2.,  nan],
         [  5.,   4.,   1.,   0.],
         [  2.,   6.,   0.,  nan]],

        [[  4.,   1.,   4.,   2.],
         [ nan,   1.,   5.,   5.],
         [  2.,   0.,   1.,   1.],
         [  6.,   3.,   6.,   5.]],

        [[  1.,   0.,   0.,   1.],
         [  1.,  nan,   2.,  nan],
         [  3.,   4.,   0.,   5.],
         [  1.,   6.,   2.,   3.]]]])

In [63]: m = 0

In [64]: np.nanmax(x, axis=tuple(i for i in range(x.ndim) if i != m))
Out[64]: array([ 5.,  6.])
```

Comment: Bingo! I thing I *used to* know that once. I was pretty sure there had to be some elegant way of doing this. Thank you!

Comment: I suppose I could even try to use `.pop()` somehow to remove it from a list before tupleing it, but I'm scared of `.pop()` for some reason.